# UIViewcontroller not getting pushed from notification

Tags: objective-c, push-notification

I have a view hierarchy as below in my storyboard

```
RootController(UIViewController)
            |
            |
MainNavigationController(UINavigationController)
            |            |                |                     |
            |            |                |                     | 
LoginController   SignInController     MainPageController    DetailControl
```

If the user is already loggedin the "MainPageController" is pushed if not then "SigInController" is pushed into navigation stack. From "MainPageController", "DetailControl" will be pushed depending on user selection.

Now this is what I am trying to do when there is a push notification.The app is in background and "MainPageController" is on top of navigation stack. The notification tap should push "DetailControl" and to achieve this, I am having this as my code

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{

    if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {

        NSLog(@"Application Active");

    } else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground){

        NSLog(@"Application Background");

    } else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive){

        [self handleNotificationWithEntity:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"entity"] withEntityId:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"entityid"]];

    } 
}


-(void) handleNotificationWithEntity:(NSString *) entity withEntityId:(NSString *) entityid
{

    RootController *rootController = (RootController *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    MainNavigationController *mvc = (MainNavigationController *)[rootController rootNavController];
    [mvc popToRootViewControllerAnimated:true];
    NSLog(@"%@",mvc.topViewController);
    // code to push detail controller here [mvc pushviewcontroller]

}
```

"Detailviewcontroller" is not getting pushed into the stack and also line "NSLog(@"%@",mvc.topViewController);" prints "LoginController" whereas I am expecting "MainPageController" should be printed out

Thanks

Comment: It looks like, from your diagram, that LoginVC is the first in the viewControllers array.  That makes it the "root" of the navigation controller.  The code does a popToRoot, then prints out the top.  So I would expect LoginController to be logged.

Comment: @dan Thanks. Even without popToRoot, I am getting LoginController printed out but the UI clearly shows main controller view

Comment: It implies that you're inspecting a different instance of the MainNavigationController than the one that has been presented.  Follow pointers from the other direction: in LoginController, let's see `NSLog(@"self=%@, nav=%@", self, self.navigationController)`.  Note the values of the pointers.  In the posted code, `NSLog(@"mvc=%@, vcs=%@", mvc, mvc.viewControllers)`.  My guess is that you'll see pointers mismatch.